# Edit the color of an email subject line in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, bestpractice, custom

Currently I was asked to format the subject line of an email, that is, to show it in green for example. I understand that this cannot be done but I wanted to confirm with you

Answer (score 0):

SMTP protocol, which manages the actual transmission of the email from Marketing Cloud and to the recipient’s inbox, doesn’t support color formatting (or any other formatting) of the subject line in any way.

You might see some emails with emojis, but as these are still just sent as Unicode text, these are commonly supported.